# segmentation fault occurs when using fclose()

Tags: c

I am creating a function that when run reads a file and brings another file to the position described in the file "PREVIOUSSTOP" (the file just contains a number) , the number is then used to move the file known as "info" up to the position described in "PREVIOUSSTOP" (if the number in "PREVIOUSSTOP" is x, the info file is moved up x many sentences). When I use fclose() in a certain function I get a Segmentation Fault.
Can someone help fix this, I have no idea on why this occurs as the file is not equal to NULL.
I have tried to use gdb to debug this but that just results in a backtrace with over 600 question marks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int stopnum = 0;

void GetInfoFromFile(FILE* info, char* Sentence1) {
    int i = 0;
    while (1) {
        char c;
        c = fgetc(info);
        Sentence1[i] = c;
        if (Sentence1[i] == '.' || Sentence1[i] == '!' || Sentence1[i] == '?') {
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    Sentence1[i + 1] = '\0';
}
void RestartPreviousTrainingSession(FILE* info) {
    FILE* stop = fopen("PREVIOUSSTOP", "r");
    if (stop != NULL) {
        char* stopstr = malloc(32);
        fgets(stopstr, 32, stop);
        int stopint = strtol(stopstr, NULL, 10);
        stopnum = stopint;
        char dummysentence[400];
        for (int i = 0; i != stopint; i++) {
            GetInfoFromFile(info, dummysentence);
        }
        /* segmentation fault occurs here */
        fclose(stop);
    } else {
        printf("OOPS\n");
    }
}
int main() {
    FILE* f = fopen("wiki.train.tokens", "r");
    RestartPreviousTrainingSession(f);
    fclose(f);
}
```

the file known as "wiki.train.tokens" can be found at https://huggingface.co/datasets/wikitext/blob/main/wikitext.py

Comment: It is likely that you are overwriting `dummysentence`, clobering `stop`. You should provide a limit  to `GetInfoFromFile()` with how much it can write to `Sentence1` (i.e. 400).

Comment: You are putting `int fgetc()` into a `char c`. Your compiler should warn you about that.

Comment: Whenever you're reading into a fixed-sized buffer, be **absolutely certain** you know the bounds into which you can write. `GetInfoFromFile` has absolutely no idea how big that buffer is, and will gleefully trash any data that's in the way.

Comment: PSA: Reading byte by byte is not an effective way to do this. Instead consider reading in fixed-sized blocks and *iterating* over the data byte by byte.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes the exact input required to reproduce the problem. This allows other people to easily test your program, by simply using copy&paste.

Comment: @tadman: But isn't that exactly what `fgetc` accomplishes?  It reads in fixed-size chunks to refill its buffer, and the calls in between just iterate over that buffer.  So other than function-call overhead, which has a good chance to be inlined away, there's no real difference, and this way certainly seems more convenient.  Of course the `char` vs `int` bug should be fixed, and the return value should be checked for EOF.

Comment: Your program relies on two files you haven't shared with us.

Comment: You are wasting time if you don't check return values.  fgetc() returns NULL on error (including EOF) and you need `c` to be an int for that.  `malloc()` returns NULL on failure.  `strtol()` may over or underflow.  It may not parse anything at all.

Comment: Additionally `int stopint = strtol(stopstr, NULL, 10);` -- what does `strtol()` return? You should at least do `long tmp = strtol(stopstr, NULL, 10);` and validate `INT_MIN <= tmp && tmp <= INT_MAX` before considering `tmp` a valid `int`. You should also use `endptr` instead of `NULL` so you can validate digits were converted by checking `stopstr != endptr`.

Comment: @NateEldredge It is buffered via `FILE*`, yes, but the overhead in banging around there is significant compared to just incrementing a pointer and reading through your own buffer, at least in my experience. The return value is a huge problem, fully agreed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not supply the input files your program relies on, and I didn't feel like search for an example.

1. I concur with @MarkAdler that you are most likely writing more than 400 bytes to dummysentence in `GetInfoFromFile()`.  The way to fix that is add a length parameter.
2. (Not fixed) In the current implementation `RestartPreviousTrainingSession()` would need to know if partial token was read as not to increment `i`.  That said, I suggest you write a function to skip `stopint` tokens instead and make it an internal affair.  You can then optimize it by reading a block of data (say, 4k), look for the `stopint`'th token, and use `ftell()` / `fseek()` to set the file position indicator.
3. (Not fixed) Avoid global variables whenever possible.  Shared state is hard to test.
4. `fgetc()` returns an `int`; needed to check if EOF was returned.  Reworked logic so the terminating `\0' ends up at the right place for all 3 ways the loop terminates.
5. `malloc()` may return NULL.
6. `strtol()` may fail to parse the number in `PREVIOUSSTOP`.  It may also return a value that is outside the range of `int` you expect.
7. Use symbolic constants instead of magic values.
8. Prefer `*` next to variable instead of type.  `FILE* a, b` is an error when you expect it to mean `FILE *a, *b`.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define TOKEN_LEN 32
int stopnum = 0;
#define MAX_SENTENCE_LEN 400

void GetInfoFromFile(FILE *info, size_t n, char Sentence1[n]) {
    int i = 0;
    for(; (!i || !strchr(".!?", Sentence1[i-1])) && i < n - 1; i++) {
        int c = fgetc(info);
        if(c == EOF)
            break;
        Sentence1[i] = c;
    }
    Sentence1[i] = '\0';
}

void RestartPreviousTrainingSession(FILE* info) {
    FILE *stop = fopen("PREVIOUSSTOP", "r");
    if (!stop) {
        printf("OOPS\n");
        return;
    }
    char *stopstr = malloc(TOKEN_LEN);
    if(!stopstr) {
        printf("malloc failed\n");
        goto out;
    }
    fgets(stopstr, TOKEN_LEN, stop);
    char *endptr;
    long stopint = strtol(stopstr, &endptr, 10);
    if(stopint < 0 || stopint > INT_MAX || stopstr == endptr) {
        printf("PREVIOUSSTOP data was invalid at %s", stopstr);
        goto out;
    }
    stopnum = stopint;

    char dummysentence[MAX_SENTENCE_LEN];
    for (int i = 0; i != stopint; i++) {
        GetInfoFromFile(info, MAX_SENTENCE_LEN, dummysentence);
    }
out:
    fclose(stop);
}

int main(void) {
    FILE *f = fopen("wiki.train.tokens", "r");
    RestartPreviousTrainingSession(f);
    fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: May want to emphasize why you did `long stopint = strtol(...)` instead of using `int stopint = ...`  Not only may `strtol()` not return a value, but it may also return a valid `long` value (the importance of which may be fluttering slightly overhead of the OP... `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Emphasized as requested.  Thanks.

Comment: Well done. You've already got my nod, but if I could give two, I would.